# Tutorial teaching Ruby syntax/knowledge required to easily learn rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I am trying to learn ROR these days and have basic knowledge of ruby, but often working with rails, I get to the point where it seems as if I don't know a bit about ruby.

Just to explain the point, in rails we use `has_many` keyword. I did not learn any such thing when I was going through ruby tutorials but just came to know that it has something to do with meta-programming in ruby (I have no idea what is meta programming).

So I would like to know if there is any book/tutorial which explain all the points/syntax/concepts of ruby, which a newbie would see while programming in rails.

Thanks to "**Jonas Elfström**", in simple words, what I am looking for is to know "**how Rails uses Ruby**"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`has_many` isn't a keyword, it's simply a class method in the `ActiveRecord::Associations` module.

It's documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) and you can even view the source if you scroll down a bit.

> Associations are a set of macro-like class methods for tying objects
>   together through foreign keys. They express relationships like
>   “Project has one Project Manager” or “Project belongs to a Portfolio”.
>   Each macro adds a number of methods to the class which are specialized
>   according to the collection or association symbol and the options
>   hash. It works much the same way as Ruby’s own attr* methods.

If you already know Ruby the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) could get you going but it might be easier to learn from one of the books listed at the [documentation page](http://rubyonrails.org/documentation) or by watching a couple of [screencasts](http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts).

For books about Ruby I've never seen such praise as what [Eloquent Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321584104) gets.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tutorial called [Learn Ruby the Hard Way](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/)
(written by Rob Sobers of Fog Creek Software)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that it's a translation of Zed Shaw’s Learn Python The Hard Way and from what I can see it covers nothing of Rails.

Comment: I didn't mention the translation thing because if you click on the link, that information is right on top of the start page. And yes, it covers only Ruby...because the question here is explicitly about Ruby.

Comment: Yes, you are right even though I would rather like to call it a question about how Rails uses Ruby.

Comment: @Janes Elfstron - You have hit the spot correctly. This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I tried lately this: http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/ which helped me a lot because there are one or two concepts that had slipped. I started long ago with an arcane version of [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/).